# No acceptable C compiler found in $PATH

Tags: compiling, install-from-source, c

I want to install one package named `speech_tools-2.1-release.tar.gz`. After I run command `./configure` in this package, it show me a message:

```
Configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH  
See 'config.log' for more details
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Run `sudo apt-get install build-essential` to install the C compiler.

Comment: I had to run apt-get update and apt-get upgrade first