# Problem with installing and compiling PHP 5.4.0

Tags: command-line, php, compiling

I have a VPS server on OVH Cloud,  Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS  with plesk 12 installed.

The server has been set up with the newest version of PHP , but Plesk can manage two different version of PHP in the same server for oldest application.

I would install with this tutorial the php-5.4.0 version : 
http://kb.sp.parallels.com/en/114753

But when I make the step

```
 ./configure
```

I have this error :

```
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/usr/local/src/php540/php-5.4.0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

May somebody help me ?

config.log

```
## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = vps117170.ovh.net
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 2.6.32-042stab094.7
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #1 SMP Wed Oct 22 12:43:21 MSK 2014

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:3156: creating cache ../config.cache
configure:3234: checking for grep that handles long lines and -e
configure:3292: result: /bin/grep
configure:3297: checking for egrep
configure:3359: result: /bin/grep -E
configure:3364: checking for a sed that does not truncate output
configure:3418: result: /bin/sed
configure:3517: checking build system type
configure:3531: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:3551: checking host system type
configure:3564: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:3584: checking target system type
configure:3597: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:3772: checking for cc
configure:3802: result: no
configure:3772: checking for gcc
configure:3802: result: no
configure:3824: error: in `/usr/local/src/php540/php-5.4.0':
configure:3827: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_YACC_set=
ac_cv_env_YACC_value=
ac_cv_env_YFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_YFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ac_cv_path_EGREP='/bin/grep -E'
ac_cv_path_GREP=/bin/grep
ac_cv_target=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
lt_cv_path_SED=/bin/sed

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ALLOCA=''
AR=''
AWK=''
CC=''
CFLAGS=''
CONFIGURE_COMMAND=' '\''./configure'\''  '\''--with-libdir=lib64'\'' '\''--cache-file=../config.cache'\'' '\''--prefix=/usr/local/php540-cgi'\'' '\''--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php540-cgi/etc'\'' '\''--disable-debug'\'' '\''--with-pic'\'' '\''--disable-rpath'\'' '\''--enable-fastcgi'\'' '\''--with-bz2'\'' '\''--with-curl'\'' '\''--with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/php540-cgi'\'' '\''--with-png-dir=/usr/local/php540-cgi'\'' '\''--enable-gd-native-ttf'\'' '\''--without-gdbm'\'' '\''--with-gettext'\'' '\''--with-gmp'\'' '\''--with-iconv'\'' '\''--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/php540-cgi'\'' '\''--with-openssl'\'' '\''--with-pspell'\'' '\''--with-pcre-regex'\'' '\''--with-zlib'\'' '\''--enable-exif'\'' '\''--enable-ftp'\'' '\''--enable-sockets'\'' '\''--enable-sysvsem'\'' '\''--enable-sysvshm'\'' '\''--enable-sysvmsg'\'' '\''--enable-wddx'\'' '\''--with-kerberos'\'' '\''--with-unixODBC=/usr'\'' '\''--enable-shmop'\'' '\''--enable-calendar'\'' '\''--without-sqlite3'\'' '\''--with-libxml-dir=/usr/local/php540-cgi'\'' '\''--enable-pcntl'\'' '\''--with-imap'\'' '\''--with-imap-ssl'\'' '\''--enable-mbstring'\'' '\''--enable-mbregex'\'' '\''--with-gd'\'' '\''--enable-bcmath'\'' '\''--with-xmlrpc'\'' '\''--with-ldap'\'' '\''--with-ldap-sasl'\'' '\''--with-mysql=/usr'\'' '\''--with-mysqli'\'' '\''--with-snmp'\'' '\''--enable-soap'\'' '\''--with-xsl'\'' '\''--enable-xmlreader'\'' '\''--enable-xmlwriter'\'' '\''--enable-pdo'\'' '\''--with-pdo-mysql'\'' '\''--with-pdo-pgsql'\'' '\''--with-pear=/usr/local/php540-cgi/pear'\'' '\''--with-mcrypt'\'' '\''--enable-intl'\'' '\''--without-pdo-sqlite'\'' '\''--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/php540-cgi/php.d'\'''
CONFIGURE_OPTIONS=' '\''--with-libdir=lib64'\'' '\''--cache-file=../config.cache'\'' '\''--prefix=/usr/local/php540-cgi'\'' '\''--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php540-cgi/etc'\'' '\''--disable-debug'\'' '\''--with-pic'\'' '\''--disable-rpath'\'' '\''--enable-fastcgi'\'' '\''--with-bz2'\'' '\''--with-curl'\'' '\''--with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/php540-cgi'\'' '\''--with-png-dir=/usr/local/php540-cgi'\'' '\''--enable-gd-native-ttf'\'' '\''--without-gdbm'\'' '\''--with-gettext'\'' '\''--with-gmp'\'' '\''--with-iconv'\'' '\''--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/php540-cgi'\'' '\''--with-openssl'\'' '\''--with-pspell'\'' '\''--with-pcre-regex'\'' '\''--with-zlib'\'' '\''--enable-exif'\'' '\''--enable-ftp'\'' '\''--enable-sockets'\'' '\''--enable-sysvsem'\'' '\''--enable-sysvshm'\'' '\''--enable-sysvmsg'\'' '\''--enable-wddx'\'' '\''--with-kerberos'\'' '\''--with-unixODBC=/usr'\'' '\''--enable-shmop'\'' '\''--enable-calendar'\'' '\''--without-sqlite3'\'' '\''--with-libxml-dir=/usr/local/php540-cgi'\'' '\''--enable-pcntl'\'' '\''--with-imap'\'' '\''--with-imap-ssl'\'' '\''--enable-mbstring'\'' '\''--enable-mbregex'\'' '\''--with-gd'\'' '\''--enable-bcmath'\'' '\''--with-xmlrpc'\'' '\''--with-ldap'\'' '\''--with-ldap-sasl'\'' '\''--with-mysql=/usr'\'' '\''--with-mysqli'\'' '\''--with-snmp'\'' '\''--enable-soap'\'' '\''--with-xsl'\'' '\''--enable-xmlreader'\'' '\''--enable-xmlwriter'\'' '\''--enable-pdo'\'' '\''--with-pdo-mysql'\'' '\''--with-pdo-pgsql'\'' '\''--with-pear=/usr/local/php540-cgi/pear'\'' '\''--with-mcrypt'\'' '\''--enable-intl'\'' '\''--without-pdo-sqlite'\'' '\''--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/php540-cgi/php.d'\'''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX=''
CXXCPP=''
CXXFLAGS=''
DEBUG_CFLAGS=''
DEFS=''
DSYMUTIL=''
ECHO='echo'
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP='/bin/grep -E'
EXEEXT=''
EXPANDED_BINDIR=''
EXPANDED_DATADIR=''
EXPANDED_EXTENSION_DIR=''
EXPANDED_LIBDIR=''
EXPANDED_LOCALSTATEDIR=''
EXPANDED_MANDIR=''
EXPANDED_PEAR_INSTALLDIR=''
EXPANDED_PHP_CONFIG_FILE_PATH=''
EXPANDED_PHP_CONFIG_FILE_SCAN_DIR=''
EXPANDED_SBINDIR=''
EXPANDED_SYSCONFDIR=''
EXTENSION_DIR=''
EXTRA_INCLUDES=''
EXTRA_LDFLAGS=''
EXTRA_LDFLAGS_PROGRAM=''
EXTRA_LIBS=''
GREP='/bin/grep'
ICU_CONFIG=''
INCLUDES=''
INCLUDE_PATH=''
INLINE_CFLAGS=''
INSTALL_IT=''
KRB5_CONFIG=''
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
LTP=''
LTP_GENHTML=''
MYSQL_INCLUDE=''
MYSQL_LIBS=''
MYSQL_MODULE_TYPE=''
NATIVE_RPATHS=''
NMEDIT=''
OBJEXT=''
OCI8_DIR=''
OCI8_ORACLE_VERSION=''
OCI8_SHARED_LIBADD=''
ODBC_INCLUDE=''
ODBC_LFLAGS=''
ODBC_LIBS=''
ODBC_TYPE=''
OPENSSL_INCDIR_OPT=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PDO_MYSQL_MODULE_TYPE=''
PDO_OCI_DIR=''
PDO_OCI_SHARED_LIBADD=''
PDO_OCI_VERSION=''
PEAR_INSTALLDIR=''
PHP_INSTALLED_SAPIS=''
PHP_LDFLAGS=''
PHP_LIBS=''
PHP_VERSION='5.4.0'
PHP_VERSION_ID='50400'
PKG_CONFIG=''
PROG_SENDMAIL=''
RANLIB=''
RE2C=''
SED='/bin/sed'
SHELL='/bin/bash'
SHLIB_DL_SUFFIX_NAME=''
SHLIB_SUFFIX_NAME=''
SNMP_CONFIG=''
STRIP=''
YACC=''
YFLAGS=''
ZEND_EXTRA_LIBS=''
abs_builddir='/usr/local/src/php540/php-5.4.0'
abs_srcdir='/usr/local/src/php540/php-5.4.0'
ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_CXX=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_vendor='unknown'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
host_alias='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='linux-gnu'
host_vendor='unknown'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
php_abs_top_builddir='/usr/local/src/php540/php-5.4.0'
php_abs_top_srcdir='/usr/local/src/php540/php-5.4.0'
php_fpm_group=''
php_fpm_localstatedir=''
php_fpm_prefix=''
php_fpm_sysconfdir=''
php_fpm_user=''
prefix='/usr/local/php540-cgi'
program_prefix='NONE'
program_suffix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
target_alias=''
target_cpu='x86_64'
target_os='linux-gnu'
target_vendor='unknown'

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""

configure: exit 1
```

Comment: It seems a permission problem. What error did you find in `config.log`?

Comment: you can install `php5` 5.5.9 easily in 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error reported in config.log is:

```
configure:3772: checking for cc
configure:3802: result: no
configure:3772: checking for gcc
configure:3802: result: no
configure:3824: error: in `/usr/local/src/php540/php-5.4.0':
configure:3827: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
```

It seems that in your $PATH variable is missing C compiler path or C compiler is not installed in your system.

In order to install it, you should follow this link:

[No acceptable C compiler found in $PATH](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237576/no-acceptable-c-compiler-found-in-path)
or
[C compiler not found, Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557029/c-compiler-not-found-ubuntu)